# Databricks - S3 other to S3 mine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, databricks

I'm using Databricks - python runtime 8.2.

There are two S3 buckets:

- Remote S3 - belongs to someone else, I have access ONLY to `bucketname/my_prefix` only
- Local S3 - belongs to me, I have full access to the bucket policy (can mount it to dbfs for example, copy files from dbfs to local s3.

My mission is to copy LOTs of files from **remote S3** which I can't mount to **local S3**.

From [Databricks Mount S3 using AWS access keys](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html#mount-a-bucket-using-aws-keys):

> Important
>
> When you mount an S3 bucket using keys, *all users* have read and write access to *all the objects* in the S3 bucket.

I have tried to use boto3 library but I cant seem to get much luck.

Essentially, is there a way to copy files from remote S3 to dbfs?

Here is one version of the code I am using - I have tried SO many other ways.

```
# test if list of days to copy is not empty; loop through each 
day and copy the s3 folder contents

if len(days_to_copy) != 0:
    for day in days_to_copy:
    #convert the items in the list from date to string and format yyyy/mm/dd
    day_to_copy = day.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    print(day_to_copy)
    source_bucket = "Remote-S3"
    source_key = "myclient/2021/10/06/part-000d339cb- 
    c000.snappy.parquet"
    target_bucket = "Local-s3"
    target_key = "{}/".format(day_to_copy)


    copy_source = {
            'Bucket': source_bucket,
            'Key': source_key
        }
    copy_target = {
            'Bucket': target_bucket,
            'Key': target_key
        }
    print('copy_source',copy_source)
    print('copy_target',copy_target)

    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'Local-s3','2021/10/06/part-000d339cb-c000.snappy.parquet' )
```

This code gives this error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? It should work I have tried it.

Comment: `ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found` is one of the errors @tomarv2

Comment: It looks like the credentials you are using do not have bucket permissions. Try using the bucket from terminal.

Comment: I have confirmed the remote bucket policy and i can ListBucket and GetObjects.